# Model and Meta-model using UML

Tags: model, uml, metamodel

Please, I need to learn how to find the meta-model of any UML model (find the meta-model of class, sequence, use case, component ... diagrams)

Cordially.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: It is complicated

Comment: Everything is complicated. Your question, as you stated it, is complicated for us.

Comment: sorry for that, because i am new in english language as new in engineering field

Comment: So you just need to know where the UML meta model can be found?

Answer (score 0):

> how to find the meta-model of any UML model

By definition the meta-model of a model defined in UML is UML itself

> find the meta-model of class, sequence, use case, component ... diagrams

This is a different question, that time you request the meta-model of UML, it is described in the *specification* (https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF, for each topic the *abstract syntax* sub-chapter gives a synthetic view with details given after) and also in the *abstract syntax metamodel* (https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20161101/UML.xmi), look also at the other documents in https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/

Probably you have first to understand what is a *model* and what is a *meta-model*